# Google Sync - Accidentally synced work contacts

Tags: google, google-contacts

Recently bought a new Android phone after switching from iOS. Moved my iCloud contacts into Google contacts and then added my personal and work Google account to my Android phone.

My Android phone is now showing 1000's of contacts because my work contacts have synced by mistake (only need the personal contacts on my phone). So I've disabled sync from my work account but all the contacts are still on my phone?

How do I 'reset' my phones contacts (and other sync info such as Calendars) so that it only shows and syncs with my personal google account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this from your phone, but you can actually restore your phone's contacts to a specific day/time. Here's how you do it in [Google Contacts Preview](https://contacts.google.com/preview/all):

[image]